# The Case of the Disappearing <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

This might be a fairly straightforward question for some but I can't figure it out. I have the following JavaScript function that gets called when you press a specific link on a page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".buttonList li").on("click", showType);
});

function showType(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var $mediaType = $(this).data("type");

    var url = "../data/media.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function (response) {
        var contentTypeHTML = '<ul class="contentList">';
        $.each(response, function (index, media_object) {
            if (media_object.type === $mediaType) {
                contentTypeHTML += '<li>' + media_object.name + '</li>';
            }
        });
        contentTypeHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#data_area').html(contentTypeHTML);

        if ($(".contentList").children().length < 1) {
            $(".contentList").html('<li>NO DATA</li>');
        }
    });

}
```

And the JSON file that's being used has the following content

```
[
    {"type" : "game","name" : "Skyrim"},
    {"type" : "game","name" : "X-Com: Enemy Within"},
    {"type" : "tvshow","name" : "The Walking Dead"},
    {"type" : "book","name" : "Revelation Space},
    {"type" : "book","name" : "Fatherland"},
    {"type" : "book","name" : "A Wise Man's Fear"}
]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is that when the JSON file gets parsed if there hasn't been any `<li>` nodes that have been created then an `<li>` node with the text of "NO DATA" should be created and appended to the `<ul>`. Now the above code works. However when I move the if statement outside of the `$.getJSON` callback function the `<li>` just appears and quickly disappears when I click the respective button (rapid clicks).

```
$.getJSON(url, function (response) {
        var contentTypeHTML = '<ul class="contentList">';
        $.each(response, function (index, media_object) {
            if (media_object.type === $mediaType) {
                contentTypeHTML += '<li>' + media_object.name + '</li>';
            }
        });
        contentTypeHTML += '</ul>';
        $('#data_area').html(contentTypeHTML);
    });
    if ($(".contentList").children().length < 1) {
            $(".contentList").html('<li>NO DATA</li>');
        }
```

Can someone help me understand why the `<li>` keeps disappearing? Or should the if statement be inside the `$.getJSON` callback function?

Comment: You might have noticed that the JSON file has an error: "Revelation Space}, needs to be "Revelation Space"},

Comment: Thank you. This was just a copy and paste error. The quote is in my actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous. Meaning that other code can run while it is running. What's happening is that your `$.getJSON` is firing and then before it finishes, the NO DATA element is being inserted, then the `$.getJSON` is finishing and overwriting it, that is why it appears/disappears. So the `if` should be inside the `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding an if/else that checks if response is empty? That way, you can determine before you print to the page if you actually need to print anything.

```
function showType(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var $mediaType = $(this).data("type");

    var url = "../data/media.json";
    $.getJSON(url, function (response) {  // When results are returned

        var contentTypeHTML = '<ul class="contentList">'; // Start UL

        if (response) { // If response exists

            $.each(response, function (index, media_object) { // Print items
                if (media_object.type === $mediaType) {                
                    contentTypeHTML += '<li>' + media_object.name + '</li>';
                }
            });

        } else { // otherwise

            contentTypeHTML += '<li>NO DATA</li>'; // Just add this
        }

        contentTypeHTML += '</ul>'; // and close it up
        $('#data_area').html(contentTypeHTML); // and put it on the page

    }); // and it should work..hopefully

}
```

Comment: Would the `else` ever get executed? Wouldn't the response contain the contents of the entire JSON file all the time making `reponse` = true?

Comment: Just stepping through the code via Chrome Developer Tools it looks like `response` will always be an array of 6 (or more items). Therefore `if(response)` will always be true from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

With the `if` outside the `getJSON` callback it is firing right after the start of the ajax call, but before it has completed.

At that point there are no children, but then when ajax completes you replace the html with at least a UL. You are only seeing it for as long as it takes to complete the ajax

I would change it to check length of response from ajax call and then you can just include the `<li>` in the new html string

```
 var contentTypeHTML = '<ul class="contentList">';
 if (!response.length) {
     contentTypeHtml += '<li>NO DATA</li>';
 } else {
     $.each(response, function (index, media_object) {
         if (media_object.type === $mediaType) {
             contentTypeHTML += '<li>' + media_object.name + '</li>';
         }
     });
 }
   contentTypeHTML += '</ul>';
   $('#data_area').html(contentTypeHTML);
```

Answer (score -1):

Fairly certain is has to do with you missing a quotation mark in your JSON, the entry

`{"type" : "book","name" : "Revelation Space},`

is missing a quote after the word "Space".

Comment: if that's the case the ajax call would never succeed and the LI would never be replaced

Comment: Thank you. This was just a copy and paste error. The quote is in my actual file.